# the multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select (case when t.freeplayabandoned != f.freeplayabandoned then 'freeplayabandoned'
             when t.freeplaydownloaded != f.freeplaydownloaded then 'freeplaydownloaded'
    end) 
from testtable t where not exists (select * from freeplay.egmfreeplay f  where f.freeplaydownloaded  = t.freeplaydownloaded)
```

I was trying to get the column names of the record of testtable which dont match with the that of freeplay.egmfreeplay

and i m getting the error the following error

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "f.freeplayabandoned" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "f.freeplaydownloaded" could not be bound.

can somebody help??

Comment: your query is all messed up.  ask a new question where you post the table definitions and what you are trying to do, that way you can get you a working a query...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

f is scoped inside the subquery inside the call to exists.  You can't use it outside the subquery.